# PHP file search lists directory as file

Tags: php, file, search

The following script is for searching for documents/files in a specified path. It works quite well except for the fact that when a subfolder has a subfolder, it lists this as an file/makes it clickable. This is not what i want. I want the script to only show the files in each folder (including files in subdirs). I hope my explanation is not to messy, haha.

Since I'm not able to post a screenshot I will try to explain.

Current folder structure:

```
vbfiles/
    -dir1/
          -subdir1/
                   -filesubdir1.doc
          -subdir2/
                   -filesubdir2.doc
          -dir1file1.doc
          -dir1file2.doc
          -dir1file3.doc
    -dir2/
          -subdir3/
                   -filesubdir3.doc
          -subdir4/
                   -filesubdir4.doc
          -dir2file4.doc
          -dir2file5.doc
          -dir2file6.doc
```

Result(what I want to remove marked with "<-- NO" :)):

```
Found 14 file(s)

dir1
 dir1file3.doc
 dir1file2.doc
 subdir1 <-- NO
 subdir2 <-- NO
 dir1file1.doc
subdir1
 filesubdir1.doc
subdir2
 filesubdir2.doc
dir2
 subdir3 <-- NO
 dir2file4.doc
 dir2file5.doc
 subdir4 <-- NO
 dir2file6.doc
subdir3
 filesubdir3.doc
subdir4
 filesubdir4.doc
```

Code:

```
<?php
define("PATH_ROOT", dirname(__FILE__) . "/");
define("PATH_FILES", PATH_ROOT . "vbfiles/");

function files($dir) {
$files = array();
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            $files[] = "$entry\n";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
return $files;
}

function getdirname($name) {
$name = substr($name, 0, -1);
$x = explode("/", $name);
return end($x);
}

function read_all_files($root = '.') {
$files = array('files' => array(), 'dirs' => array());
$directories = array();
$last_letter = $root[strlen($root) - 1];
$root = ($last_letter == '\\' || $last_letter == '/') ? $root : $root . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

$directories[] = $root;

while (sizeof($directories)) {
    $dir = array_pop($directories);
    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
                continue;
            }
            $file = $dir . $file;
            if (is_dir($file)) {
                $directory_path = $file . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
                array_push($directories, $directory_path);
                $files['dirs'][] = $directory_path;
            } elseif (is_file($file)) {
                $files['files'][] = $file;
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
}

return $files;
}

$searchstr = $_GET['search'];
$type = "files";

if ($type == "files") {

$folders = read_all_files(PATH_FILES);
$found = array();
$count = 0;
sort($folders['files']);
sort($folders['dirs']);
foreach ($folders['dirs'] as $folder) {
    foreach (files($folder) as $filename) {
        $m = preg_match("#$searchstr#si", $filename, $ids);
        if ($m) {
            $found[getdirname($folder)][] = $filename;
            $count++;
        }
    }
}
$dir = "vbfiles/";
if (count($found)) {
    echo "<h3>Found " . $count . " file(s)</h3>";
    foreach ($found as $folder => $files) {
        echo "<ul id='navi_lvl0'>
<li class='folder'>" . $folder . "</li>
<ul id='navi_lvl1'>";

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            echo "<li class='document'><a href='$dir$folder/$file' target='_blank'>" . $file . "</a></li>";
        }
        echo "</ul></ul>";
    }
} else {
    echo "No files found";
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This function lists files from a directory. It approaches to nested child directories also. I wrote this when i required  the same functionality.

```
/**
 * Return files of desired extension from a directory
 *
 * @author Pankaj Garg <garg.pankaj15@gmail.com>
 *
 * @param string $_dirPath   path to directory
 * @param string $_extension desired file extension
 * @param int    $_before    files to get before this time (in seconds)
 * @param int    $_limit     no of files
 *
 * @return array $_scannedFiles  array of files
 */
function ScanFilesFromDirectory($_dirPath, $_extension, $_before = 0, $_limit = 10)
{
    $_scannedFiles = array();

    if (empty($_extension)) {
        return $_scannedFiles;
    }
    if (!is_dir($_dirPath)) {
        return $_scannedFiles;
    }

    //If extension starting with '.', then remove it
$_extension = (stripos($_extension, '.') === 0) ? substr($_extension, 1) : $_extension;
$_handler   = opendir($_dirPath);

while ($_fileName = readdir($_handler)) {
    //for files starting with '.'
    if (stripos($_fileName, '.') === 0) {
        continue;
    }

    if (is_dir($_dirPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_fileName)) {
        $_scannedFiles = array_merge($_scannedFiles, ScanFilesFromDirectory($_dirPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_fileName, $_extension, $_before, $_limit));
    } else if (is_file($_dirPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_fileName)) {
        if (preg_match('/' . preg_quote($_extension) . '$/', $_fileName)) {
            if (($_before != 0 && time() - filemtime($_dirPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_fileName)) < $_before) {
                continue;
            }
            $_scannedFiles[] = substr($_fileName, 0, -strlen($_extension) - 1);
        }
    }
    if (count($_scannedFiles) >= $_limit) {
        break;
    }
}
closedir($_handler);

return $_scannedFiles;
}
```